# Simulating Events and Delegates in real life scenario

Tags: c#, delegates

I would like to teach students about event and delegates with real life example.I would like to relate it to real life event.

I would like to convert the following real life scenario to events and delegates.

I have a heartbeat monitor.Whenever my heart beat rates are abnormal ,my doctor will get notified with my abnormal heart rates.

I would like to write a code in C# 4.0 to map it into events and delegates.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds fine and noble. What's your question?

Comment: @Damien - The question is how to write code to express this idea

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code :

```
class MyHeartBeatMonitor
{
    public event EventHandler<AbnormalHeartRateSimulation> Abnormalheartbeats;

    public void NotifyFamilyDoctor()
    {
        EventHandler<AbnormalHeartRateSimulation> handler 
                                                   = Abnormalheartbeats;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            AbnormalHeartRateSimulation simulatedRates =
                                        new AbnormalHeartRateSimulation();
            simulatedRates.heartRate = 140;
            handler(this, simulatedRates);
        }


  }
}

public class AbnormalHeartRateSimulation : EventArgs
    {
        public int heartRate { get; set; }
    }


class FamilyDoctor
  {
   public void EventHandler(
                          object sender,AbnormalHeartRateSimulation args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Your Patient's HearRate is " + args.heartRate);
    }


    }

class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       MyHeartBeatMonitor monitor = new MyHeartBeatMonitor();
       FamilyDoctor doctor = new FamilyDoctor();
       monitor.Abnormalheartbeats += doctor.EventHandler;
       monitor.NotifyFamilyDoctor();
       Console.ReadKey(true);
      }
}
```

Go ahead and customize it based on your requirements. All the best!